# TFS Build agent, rename _work folder to a shorter name

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS2018 and I am getting the following error during the GetSources step

```
2017-11-22T10:22:35.4137749Z TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters: C:\agent\_work\1\s\myverylongfoldertoalongfilenamepath. Specify a shorter path.
2017-11-22T10:22:35.4450272Z ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc get /version:58632 /recursive /overwrite C:\agent\_work\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.
```

I want to shorten the Build agent folder names. Is it possible to rename the _work folder to e.g. w ?

Comment: Hi @Mat I rephrased the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error you got  in short currently its the TFVC limitation, from
>
> ```
> Must not contain more than 259 Unicode characters for a single folder or file name.
> ```
>
> *Source Link: [Version control paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions#version-control-paths)*

You could [change the Build Agent Working Directory](https://www.johandorper.nl/log/tfs-vnext-change-build-agent-working-directory) by reconfigured the build agent.  You could use  `a` instead of `agent` and got `c:\a\_work\1\s`  and `_work` to `w`.

Otherwise you have to manually **tweak your file/folder structure**  in TFS source control to bypass this issue. From  `C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestCaseProject` to `C:\Agent\_work\1\s\TestCasePro`

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT I was able to change the _work folder to w during the configuration of the agent

Comment: @doorman Sorry haven't  tried this ,this could not be done when xaml build. Have update my reply.